# Saving Google Trends Graph as Static Image?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-trends

I am trying to save Google Trend's widget that outputs a line graph, map, etc. as an image using Python. The URL I am using has only one widget on the page, and I would like to save it as a static image. I want to save this image based on the size of the widget; I do not want to screenshot the page and crop this image. Could someone assist with this please? BS4 is not picking up any widgets when I search for them. I know that I haven't added any steps to save the widget because I haven't found it yet. The URL and code is below:

https://trends.google.com/trends/embed/explore/TIMESERIES?req=%7B%22comparisonItem%22%3A%5B%7B%22keyword%22%3A%22Coronavirus%22%2C%22geo%22%3A%22%22%2C%22time%22%3A%222020-01-15%202020-03-02%22%7D%5D%2C%22category%22%3A0%2C%22property%22%3A%22%22%7D&tz=300&forceMobileMode=false&isPreviewMode=true&eq=date%3D2020-01-15%25202020-03-02%26q%3DCoronavirus&hl=enUS

```
import datetime
import requests
import warnings
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from [redacted] import SETTINGS


d = datetime.date.today()
current_month = f"{d.month:02d}"
current_day = f"{d.day:02d}"

URL1 = 'https://trends.google.com/trends/embed/explore/TIMESERIES?req=%7B%22comparisonItem%22%3A%5B%7B%22keyword%22%3A%22Coronavirus%22%2C%22geo%22%3A%22%22%2C%22time%22%3A%222020-01-15%202020-'
URL2 = str(current_month)+"-"+str(current_day)
URL3 = '%22%7D%5D%2C%22category%22%3A0%2C%22property%22%3A%22%22%7D&tz=300&forceMobileMode=false&isPreviewMode=true&eq=date%3D2020-01-15%25202020-'
URL4 = URL2
URL5 = '%26q%3DCoronavirus&hl=enUS'

URL = URL1 + URL2 + URL3 + URL4 + URL5
print(URL)


def get_widget():
    #gets rid of request errors
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='Unverified HTTPS request')
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore',InsecureRequestWarning)
    #from internal core 
    proxies=SETTINGS['proxies']    
    resp = requests.get(URL, proxies=proxies, verify=False)
    html = resp.text
    #finds widgets
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    tags = soup.findAll("h2", {"class": "embed-logo"})
    for tag in tags:
        print(tag.getText())
    #another attempt to find the widgets
    widgets = soup.find_all('trends-wrapper ng-scope')
    number_of_widgets = len(widgets)
    print('Number of widgets: ' + str(number_of_widgets))

get_widget()
```

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium, you can take a partial screenshot of the chart only, then you won't have to crop the image. I see no other way to get that chart, other than downloading the data and creating the chart with Python.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

URL = "https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=coronavirus&geo=US"
print(URL)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
sleep(10)
chart = driver.find_element_by_class_name('widget-container')
chart.screenshot("chart.png")
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am trying to do this without Selenium--I don't want to install a webdriver to my path. Is there no other way to achieve this?